# Installed package component not visible in community site but visible in sandbox

Tags: community, customer-community, customer-portal, digital-experience

I installed a package Milestones PM and used in community site. Created contact and enabled as partner and logged in as experience user. After login the compoennt is not visible. When I tried to open digital experience--> all sites-->work space---> builder, component is displaying. I am not sure where I missed.
Contact profile permission also given in digital experience.
Publised the component also.
[image]
Please help me.

Comment: Not knowing what the component shows I can only suggest you check permissions that it may require. Check the vendor's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to check below

1. Make sure all the permissions to the objects involved in building that component is assigned to the Community Profile your experience cloud site user has access to.
2. Make sure dashboard folder and dashboard component is available to the Community User profile or the user roles.